# use a specific value from JSON response from GET request via fetch --> to a POST request

Tags: javascript, html, fetch

the main goal here is to use the part of the response, in the 2nd POST requset.

Let me explain -
given the following endpoint:

```
https://www.example.com/Applications/?api-version=1&_cacheToken=1675420688869
```

the response from sending a GET request to the endpoint is :

```
{"field1":"","Items":[{"Name":"app:\/appname","field2":"appnumber","field3":"appvers","Status":"Ready","Parameters":[],"health":"Ok","kind":"numbers","ids":{"id":[]},"met":{"met1":{}},"Id":"1"}]}
```

I would like to use only the value of "appname".
hence i'm using it as follows -

```
---SNIP---
...
.then(data => {
  const appname = data.Items[0].Name;
  const appname_updated = appname.replace('app:/', '');
...
---SNIP---
```

I would like to use it with a second fetch request, but this time in a form of POST (in the endpoint itself and in the body):

```
return fetch('https://www.example.com/deploy/'+appname_updated+'/?api-version=1', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
    mode: 'no-cors',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      appname: appname_updated,
      field1: "blah"
    })
  });
})
```

How this can possible be done ? so the first GET will be sent, receieve 200 ok,
and once it got the 200 status, the POST should send right after with the proper
values populated.

No matter what i've tried so far, nothing seems to be send the second POST rquest.
(I've tried it with asyc/wait etc.)

----- update ----
this is the full code -

```
<script>
  const firstUrl = "https://example.com/Applications/?api-version=1";
  const secondUrl = "https://example.com/deploy/";

  async function fetchData() {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(firstUrl, {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
      });
      if (response.status === 200) {
        const data = await response.json();
        const appname_updated = data.Items[0].Id;

        const secondResponse = await fetch(secondUrl + appname_updated + '/?api-version=1', {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            appname: appname_updated,
            ...rest of JSON
          })
        });
        if (secondResponse.status === 200) {
          console.log("POST request successful");
        } else {
          console.error("Error with POST request");
        }
      } else {
        console.error("Error with GET request");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error with fetch: ", error);
    }
  }

  fetchData();
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`'no-cors'` tells `fetch` to fail silently if you try to do anything which requires permission from CORS.

Making a cross-origin request with `'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` requires permission from CORS.

Don't use `'no-cors'`.

Comment: in more context -
both requests meant to be sent via an embedded iframe that i control, hence the 'no-cors'.

Comment: @wicked_proxy — That makes no sense at all. If you control the iframe then you control the origin. Even if it did make sense, it wouldn't change the very simple facts laid out in the first two paragraphs of this answer.

Comment: thanks, so given that, both requests should executed once no-cors is removed ?

Comment: Maybe. `---SNIP---` makes it hard to see any possible timing issues. Removing `no-cors` might expose an error that means `https://www.example.com` needs to be edited to grant permission using CORS. But removing `no-cors` will fix the *current* issue that you're asking about.

Comment: got it, let me add a bit more info.
thanks again for following up on this.

Comment: hey, i've updated the full script.